# Proper way to prevent deallocation using std::allocator and std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

As the title says, I wonder if this is a proper way to prevent deallocation in `vector<T> a` when moving `vector<T> a` to`vector<T> b`.

**Vector header:**

```
template<class T, class A = std::allocator<T>>
class vector
{
    typedef typename A::size_type size_type;

    A alloc;
    T* start;
    T* end;

    public:

            explicit vector(size_type n, const T& val = T(), const A& =A());
            vector(vector&&);
            ~vector();

};
```

**Constructor:**

*Note:* allocate can throw `std::bad_alloc`.

```
template<class T, class A>
vector<T,A>::vector(size_type n, const T& val, const A& a)
    : alloc(a)
{

    start = alloc.allocate(n); //allocate memory for n elements.
    end = start + n;

    for(auto p = start; p!=end; p++)
            alloc.construct(p, val); //construct val at allocated memory.

}
```

**Move constructor:**

*Question:* Is this a proper way to move vector v?

```
template<class T, class A>
vector<T,A>::vector(vector&& v)
    :alloc(v.alloc)             // copy the allocator in v.
{

    start = std::move(v.start); // move the pointer previously returned by allocator. 
    end = std::move(v.end);     // same boundary value.
    v.start = v.end = nullptr;  // nullptr to prevent deallocation when v is destroyed.
}
```

**Destructor:**

*Question:* According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate), `allocator::deallocate(p, n)` deallocates memory from a pointer previously returned by `allocator` and `n` must be equal to the number of elements allocated for. What if this is not the case? My answer would be that `allocator::deallocate` does nothing if the pointer or the number of elements, `n`, is not equal to previous call to `allocator::allocate(n)`. Is this true?

```
template<class T, class A>
vector<T, A>::~vector()
{
    for(auto p = start; p!=end; p++)
            alloc.destroy(p);           //Destroy objects pointed to by alloc. 

    alloc.deallocate(start, end-start); //Deallocate memory.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a proper way to move vector v?

Seems fine, but `std::move` is redundant with pointers. Also, you don't deallocate `end`, so you don't need to set it to null.

> What if this is not the case? My answer would be that allocator::deallocate does nothing if the pointer or the number of elements, n, is not equal to previous call to allocator::allocate(n). Is this true?

No, the behaviour is undefined. You must pass the same `n`.